# The method add(String) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments (List)

Tags: android, checkbox

when i add the selected items from custom listview with checkbox to arraylist in android,there is an error showing in the line .

```
selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position));
```

> The method add(String) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (List)

This is my code

```
  public class HomePage extends Activity {
private ListView listView1;
ListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

    List device_data[] = new List[]
                {
        new List(R.drawable.ic_pic , "DCIM"),
        new List(R.drawable.ic_pic, "Videos"),
        new List(R.drawable.ic_pic, "Music"),
        new List(R.drawable.ic_pic, "Mobile Uploads"),
        new List(R.drawable.ic_pic, "Personal Folder")

                     };



    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this,  R.layout.list_viewrow, device_data);

        listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

       View header =      (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header, null);
       listView1.addHeaderView(header);

       listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

       Log.i("check box status", ""+ListAdapter.ListHolder.class);


       }
   private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<List> {
    Context context; 
      int layoutResourceId;   
      boolean checkvalue;
       List data[] = null;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        final ListHolder holder;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ListHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.checkbox=(CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.check);
            holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {

                    //Log.i("clicked", ""+holder.checkbox.isChecked());
                    checkvalue=holder.checkbox.isChecked();
                     if(checkvalue=holder.checkbox.isChecked()==true){
                        startNewActivity();
                    }
                }


              });

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ListHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        List list = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(list.title);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(list.icon);

        return row;
    }


    class ListHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
        CheckBox checkbox;
    }
     private void startNewActivity() {

             Button btn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
             btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                         SparseBooleanArray checked = listView1.getCheckedItemPositions();
                        final ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

                         for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                             // Item position in adapter
                             int position = checked.keyAt(i);


                             if (checked.valueAt(i))
                                             **selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position));**
                         }
                        String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];

                        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
                            outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
                        }
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                               CheckedValues.class);
                         Bundle b = new Bundle();
                         b.putStringArray("selectedItems", outputStrArr);


                         intent.putExtras(b);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked View "+checkvalue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

}
```

}

Thank in advance

Comment: You could at least highlight the line for us, save having to read a hundred lines of irrelevant code.

Comment: what is it you don't understand ?

Comment: (i guess adding `.title` would solve it, though without knowing what you aretrying to do it is not that obvious)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the error is at this line:

```
selectedItems.add( adapter.getItem(position));
```

You've declared the adapter to manage an array of `List` objects. You declared `selectedItems` to be an `ArrayList<String>`. You can't add an object of type `List` to an `ArrayList` that is expecting `String` elements. You probably want something like:

```
selectedItems.add((String) adapter.getItem(position).get(1));
```

Note that you would be much better off declaring an aggregation class:

```
class Data {
    int resourceId;
    String name;
}
```

Then the compiler could enforce type safety and you wouldn't have to cast when accessing elements of the list. You would also eliminate the autoboxing of the resource IDs.

Answer (score 0):

your error occurs in this line

```
selectedItems.add( adapter.getItem(position));
```

Your item is your own List-Item and so you cant add it to a `ArrayList<String>`.

Cheers

Comment: thanks for the help,i s there any lternate method to add selected items into arraylist?

Comment: I dont't now your List-Class but you could create a `toString` method for your list items. Then you can call it `selectedItems.add( adapter.getItem(position.toString));` You could also change the `ArrayList<String> selectedItems` to `ArrayList<List> selectedItems`